# Excel: get a value based on exact text in a cell

Tags: excel

I have a cell that I need to input a value based on the size listed in another cell

so cell A1 has either "Small" "Medium" or "Large"

and in cell A2 I want it to show 1, 0, -1 respectively depending on the size

please help

Comment: Use a lookup table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MATCH:

```
=2-MATCH(A1,{"Small","Medium","Large"},0)
```